# Can I put a 9.5 mm SSHD disk in an only 7 mm laptop HDD slot?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sshd

Can I put a 9.5 mm SSHD disk in an only 7 mm laptop HDD slot? Putting bigger drive in smaller slot?

I have a Lenovo flex 2. It's hdd model is a slim WD Blue WD10SPCX with 7 mm height. Unfortunately it got about 1700 bad sector and only remained 9 % of it's life. I want to buy a SSHD like **Seagate Hybrid Drives ST1000LM014** 1TB MLC/8GB. But it's height is 9.5 mm.

The question boils down to the precision of height specifications on drives and laptop slots.

Comment: It depends on the size of the compartment.  The original drive may not be the max that will fit.  Cut some rectangles of cardboard until you have 2.5mm thickness, add it to the original drive, and see if it fits.

Comment: It all depends.  Measure the amount of extra space the current drive actually has.  If the enclosure is larger then 9.5 mm its possible the drive will fit.

Comment: What is the source of the 7mm spec?  Is it a spec for the laptop or that was simply the thickness of the original drive?  The wording of the question is confusing.